Thailand : Are those addresses valid and what do they mean?
A lot of our Thai customers send us addresses like this :
region : Western Province
city : 
postcode : 13505
street number : 56
residential address: 1

I'm puzzled by that last line.
For Western users I guess that would be the street name.
But what do Thai users mean when they enter "1" there?

Did you checked up some addresses on google maps?

I didn't think about it. I'm completely foreign to this area of expertise. Good idea.

I can't find any of those addresses. Google understands no more than I do what they actually mean, but I still can't tell if the address is fake or if it's just an accepted convention in Thailand (no street names, or numbered street names, in some areas)

Visit the webiste of some companies or governmant agencies in Thailand to see what kind of address format they use. OpenStreetMap could also help: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4188283689 Maybe it would also help to know what you use this for. You want to geocode the addresses? See also Wikipedia: postal codes in Thailand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Thailand

Please have a look on addr:xxx tags in OpenStreetMap data for Thailand: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1VjM They are a/ bit different to what we are using in the West, b/ bit inconsistent in their structure as well.
